# MySQL Left Join Limit on subquery selecting min(value)

Tags: mysql, left-join

Sorry if the title is not very clear...

I have two tables `products` and `images`,

related on `products`.`product_id` = `images`.`product_id`,

each product has several images related to it on the `images` table,

both tables have a column width values I wish to ORDER BY (`product_order` and `image_order`).

The result I'm looking for is a list with all the `published` `products` with **only one image (and one result) per product**, the image should be the one with the lowest value on the column `image_order`.

I put together the code below from other answers I found here and it's working, the only problem is that the column `image_order` allows duplicates, so where there are images for the same product with the same value in `image_order` I'm getting multiple results per product.

```
SELECT products.*, images.image_name, images.image_order

FROM products

LEFT JOIN images ON (
    images.product_id = products.product_id 
    AND images.image_order = (
        SELECT min(image_order) 
        FROM images 
        WHERE product_id = products.product_id
    )
)

WHERE products.published = 1
ORDER BY products.product_order ASC
```

***edit** (My tables):*

Table **products**

```
product_id  |  product_name  |  product_order
____________|________________|_________________
     1      |  Fist Product  |        1
     2      | Second Product |        2
     3      | Third Product  |        3
```

Table **images**

```
 image_id   |   product_id   |    image_name    |  image_order
____________|________________|__________________|_________________
     1      |       1        |  Fist Image URL  |        1
     2      |       1        | Second Image URL |        1
     3      |       2        | Third Image URL  |        1
     4      |       3        | Fourth Image URL |        1
```

The results I'm getting from this Query:

1. Firt Product   + First Image
2. **Firt Product   + Second Image**
3. Second Product + ThirdImage
4. Third Product  + FourthImage

The results I need:

1. Firt Product   + First Image
2. Second Product + ThirdImage
3. Third Product  + FourthImage

Comment: Executing the query as is should return only one row. Doesn't It?

Comment: No. If I have two images where `product_id = 1` and `image_order = 1` then I get two results for the product with `product_id = 1`

Comment: Then, I'm thinking your left join isnt't the way to go... The subquery is working, but it works twice

Comment: I suggest showing some sample of the data showing multiple products, one/multiple images and show WHAT you want.  You could have 10 items published (ie: = 1 flag), 3 products have only a single image, and the rest have two or more images.  Data sample will definitely help you get your answer.

Comment: @DRapp I edited my question. Hope that helps. I'm noob width MySQL and having got this far with the query I'm kind of lost with how to explain it :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this, but it's not the best option. With further knowlodge of your tables a better answer might be possible:

```
select products.*,
(
    select image_name from images
    where product_id = products.product_id
    order by image_order asc
  limit 1
) as 'image_name'
from products
WHERE products.published = 1
ORDER BY products.product_order ASC
```

Comment: Thanks! I will surely try this. Since the site I'm working on don't have that much traffic I don't need a very efficient query, just one that works! :)

Comment: Working perfectly for what I need! Tanks again :)